# merge multiple lists into one list in python using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

I have a code that return the max value of each column in the dataframe  until now it returns each value as a seperated list so if i have 3 values it returns 3 list each list contains one item.

What i want is to return one list that contains all the items.

```
returned list: 
[1]
[509]
[92]
[332]
[14]

expected result:
[1,509,92,332,14]
```

## code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Dataframe({'event_type': ['watch movie ', 'stay at home', 'swimming','camping','meeting'], 
               'year_month': ['2020-08', '2020-05', '2020-02','2020-06','2020-01'],
                'event_mohafaza':['loc1','loc3','loc2','loc5','loc4'],
                 ' number_person ':[24,39,20,10,33],})

grouped_df=pd.crosstab(df['year_month'], df[event_type])
print(type(grouped_df))
                        
for x in grouped_df.columns:                
     mx = []
     maxvalue =grouped_df[x].max() 
     mx.append(maxvalue)
     print(mx)
```

Comment: Your code is not working. Please correct it: `Dataframe` ⇾ `DataFrame`, `df[event_type]` ⇾ `df['event_type']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No need for using `grouped_df.colums`; a dataframe iterates over columns *anyway*:

   ```
   for x in grouped_df:
   ```
2. In your `for` loop you every time cleared your list `mx`; you probably want to clear it *only once,* i.e. *before* your `for` loop:

   ```
   mx = []
   for x in grouped_df:
   ```
3. In your `for` loop you every time print your list `mx` (freshly cleared and appended with only one — the current — element).
   You probably want to print it *only once, after all elements will be appended,* i.e. *after*  your loop.

So your corrected code should be:

```
mx = []
for x in grouped_df:
    maxvalue = grouped_df[x].max() 
    mx.append(maxvalue)
print(mx)
```

---

*Note:*

Manually iterating over data in pandas is *always suspicious* — generally, there is often a more elegant “pandasonic” solution.

In your case you may simply print

```
list(grouped_df.max())
```

or

```
grouped_df.max().to_list()
```

(`grouped_df.max()` is a *series*, the `list()` function or the `.to_list()` method makes a *list* from it.)

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation, MarianD!

Comment: thank you for your help i did not know for the **elegant “pandasonic” solution**.

Answer (score 2):

You can just define your list before you enter the loop and print it afterwards.

```
mx = []
for x in grouped_df.columns:                
     maxvalue = grouped_df[x].max() 
     mx.append(maxvalue)
print(mx)
```

You can also use the builtin `max` function.

```
print(grouped_df.max())
```